# framework is red in Xcode but no error with building

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, cocoapods

The file is displayed in red in Xcode as shown in the image. I'm developing a Flutter app and buid to ios simulator succeeds without any problems.
I have no idea what the cause is. Also, when I check the corresponding file with alfred, the path seems to be different ...
I tried pod update , but nothing changed.
Xcode ver : 12.5.1
use m1 mac.and installed cocoapod by homebrew.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means that your framework is not found... if you right clic on them and select show in finder, it will probably not take you anywhere, as it does not know where they are... you can just re-include them in your project, by dragging and dropping them in your project directory and that should auto-correct so that they don't show in red...

You may also want to check 'Framework Search Paths' under the build settings of your project/target... to make sure it can find them, the paths to the location of your frameworks should all be included here (it's easier if yo have all your frameworks in one folder)

But to make them not show up as red, just drag and drop them from wherever they are again into your project, and then delete the red one and you should be good...

Comment: All ".framework" files are in the form of folders when I search with alfred, not in one folder. I also didn't know where the Framework folder was ..

Comment: This is because frameworks are technically folders, and they can contain, files, images, etc. but if they have the .framework extension, you can just drag it in and it will bring all the files it contains with it, and also the red error marks should go away. You can have your frameworks in different folders or in the same folder, but always make sure if they are in separate folders that the framework search path is updated to include the path to a new framework if it's on a separate folder